# Flex: find next instance of string in TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I have a TextArea, a TextInput and a button. When text is entered into the TextInput the TextArea is searched for the matching string, however it only highlights the first found instance of the string. How can I do a 'find next' type of operation.

```
protected function searchBtn_clickHandler():void
        {
            text = mainTextField.text;
            search_Str = searchTxt.text;

            var search_result:int = text.search(search_Str);
            trace(search_result);
            mainTextField.setFocus();
            mainTextField.selectRange(search_result,search_result+search_Str.length);
        }
```

**EDIT**

```
protected function searchBtn_clickHandler():void
        {
            text = mainTextField.text;
            search_Str = searchTxt.text;

            search_result = text.search(search_Str);
            trace(search_result);
            mainTextField.setFocus();
            mainTextField.selectRange(search_result,search_result+search_Str.length);
            oldSearch_result = search_result;
        }

        protected function findNextBtn_clickHandler():void
        {
            search_Str = searchTxt.text;

            // truncate the text using substring; this gives you everything in mainTextField after your previous search results
            var truncatedText:String = mainTextField.text.substring(oldSearch_result+search_Str.length);

            search_result = truncatedText.search(search_Str);
            mainTextField.setFocus();
            // when you select the range, you want to offset your result index w/ the characters your chopped off  
            mainTextField.selectRange(oldSearch_result+search_Str.length+search_result,search_result+search_Str.length);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user clicks "find next" button, just truncate the text based on the search_str.length and search_result--in memory--and perform the search again.

```
protected function searchAgain_ClickHandler(event:Event):void{
  search_Str = searchTxt.text;

  // truncate the text using substring; this gives you everything in mainTextField after your previous search results
  var truncatedText = mainTextField.text.substring(oldSearchResult+search_Str.length);

  var search_result:int = truncatedText.search(search_Str);
  mainTextField.setFocus();
 // when you select the range, you want to offset your result index w/ the characters your chopped off  
mainTextField.selectRange(oldSearchResult+search_Str.length+search_result,search_result+search_Str.length);

}
```

More info on [substring](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substring%28%29)

---

Edit 12/7/2011

Here is a full code sample showing this approach working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            import spark.layouts.HorizontalLayout;

            protected var oldSearchResult :int =0;

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var search_Str : String = searchTxt.text;

                // truncate the text using substring; this gives you everything in mainTextField after your previous search results
                var truncatedText : String;
                truncatedText = mainTextField.text.substring(oldSearchResult);

                var search_result:int = truncatedText.search(search_Str);
                mainTextField.setFocus();
                // when you select the range, you want to offset your result index w/ the characters your chopped off  
                if(search_result != -1){
                    mainTextField.selectRange(oldSearchResult+search_result,oldSearchResult+search_result+search_Str.length);
                    oldSearchResult = oldSearchResult+search_result+search_Str.length;
                } else {
                    Alert.show('no more results');
                }

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Form height="100%" width="100%">
        <s:FormItem label="Search Text" layout="{new HorizontalLayout()}" width="100%" >
            <s:TextInput id="searchTxt" text="the" />
            <s:Button label="Search Next" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:TextArea  id="mainTextField">
                <s:text>
                    The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogs and Landed on the Other Side of the River, bouncing back and forth between two turtles in an attempt to escape the flying vulture.
                </s:text>
            </s:TextArea>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: One followup question. When I press the Find Next button it highlightes everything before the next instance of the string. I set oldSearch_result = search_result+search_Str.length;. What should it be?

Comment: I'd have to see and debug your code.  It sounds like you're using the wrong values to select the range; or possibly starting the search at the wrong location.  I beleive the concept I explain in my answer is write, but I wrote it in the browser, so I may have got some intricacies wrong.

Comment: I've made an edit showing my code. If I have text in my TextArea, the find button will find the first instance of the string in searchTxt, but when I click find next, it highlightes everything directly BEFORE the next occurrence of the string, so it's ending the highight where it should be starting it if that makes sense.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a full code sample demonstrating my solution.

Comment: Let me know if it solves the issue. :=)  If it does, does that mean I get the bounty?

Comment: It worked perfect Flextras thanks! I thought the bounty was auto. How do I award it?

Comment: You should be able to click a button, +150 or whatever the same way you chose my answer.  The bounty is only automatic if answers are created after the bounty is started.  Mine was there before the bounty was started, so I don't think I'm eligible unless you explicitly award it to me.  More info on bounties are here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty .

Comment: Got it :) the +150 wasnt showing up i my Blackberry browser. Sorry bout that.